# 2 circle colliders causing lag in player movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, lag

I am making a game in Unity 2d where if you are in the range of a magnet, you get attracted to it. Attached to the player are 2 circle colliders: one is set as a trigger, which radius can increase or decrease to alter the magnet's range, and the other one isn't set as a trigger to allow it to rest on platforms. I am using this code: `transform.Translate(3 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);` to move the player forward. The player movement is really laggy when it is touching the ground, but it is smoother when it is in the air. The camera movement is silky smooth once the project is exported, so I do not think that it is because I have a slow computer for only the player is laggy. Could someone help me solve this problem? Also it is important to note that when either circle collider is removed, the movement is smooth, so it isn't a problem with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the main issue is that the collision with the ground causes problems with the transform.Translate. I suggest some changes:

**CHANGING THE TRIGGER**
You should move the collision with the trigger on the magnet, it's way easier for the future if you want to add new magnets and you will see also the application with my changes

**ADDING FORCE**
Instead of doing a transform.Translate you should add a force so you keep the physics working well and it won't look buggy!
You should do:

```
FixedUpdate()
{
   rb.AddForce(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) * 2);
   
}
```

We use FixedUpdate() because it keeps physics working well and rb is the rigidbody of the player and Vector2.distance can be Vector2.right, it depends on what you imagine. If you work with distance force will increase if you go closer.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was wondering how would I change the range of the player if the collision detection is on the magnets. I had done this originally, but thought that it would make more sense if I increased the range of the player rather than increase the range of all the magnets. It would do the same thing, but easier. Once again, thank you so much, I will let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Sorry just realised that my game explanation wasn't great. In each level, there are about 10 magnets and one player. The player can either attract or repel from the magnets and uses these physics to complete the level

Comment: @RAW_tech if you have multiple magnets than use the AddForce to the rigidbody of the player ( you can access to it by having a tag to the player and than GameObject player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Tag")) and than put a value like distance and so if you get closer to magnets force will be more powerful than in the border

Comment: I am so sorry, I think I still haven't explained it right. My player is constantly moving forward like in Geometry Dash. The script responsible for this is transform.Translate(3 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);. I think your first answer was right, but when I tried running it, it gave me the error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Comment: write rb.AddForce(new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - player.transform.position.x), Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - player.transform.position.y) * value);

Comment: @RAW_tech where "value" is just a number to change the strength of the speed, if it is public you can do with inspector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225822/discussion-between-raw-tech-and-leoverload).